# How I remove this email field from registration page without using custom provider? Membership provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I am using membership provider have following fields in registration page in CreateUserWizardStep

```
1-UserName
2-Password
3-Confirm Password
4-Emial
```

When I create account then accounts created successfully.User AspnetMembership provider
But my question is I remove email field from registration page,it not allow to save.
show message `'please enter valid email'.`
How I remove this email field from registration page.I dont want to use custom provider
**Can some body give me some TIP to remove email field successfully?**

***I also set RequireEmail="false" in CreateUserWizard tag***

Thanks in Advance

Comment: On the actual email field can't you specify Required=False?

Comment: Are you using a field validator? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972961.aspx

Comment: Actually username in my registration form is also email.So I dont need of email address.I removed it from form but when I try to create user then it gives me error 'Please enter valid email address'

Comment: Is there a field validator on the page?  If there is a field validator (probably a RequiredFieldValidator) then it will need to be removed or configured to not require the email field.  Maybe you could post the resulting ASPX code?

Comment: No field validator here against email.I removed email section completely

Comment: At this point you may want to add some additional information.  I am assuming that your 'please enter valid email' message shows on the page, but this would neccesitate a field validator or some other control to check the values before they are submitted.  It might also be helpful to have the ASPX for the page.  Edit: on second though, search your aspx for "please enter valid email" or what ever the message is (unless this is a multi-language page in which case you would need to search the resource file, then find any controls using the string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way:

1.Remove the `email` field from the `createuserwizard` especialy if you're doing it for `new activation`.

2.Assign a custom email for all users by handling the CreatingUser Event.

For example `noreply@yoursitename.com`

3.Disable `RequiresUniqueEmail` in your `web.config`

Answer (score 2):

need to remove email text box and `RequiredFieldValidator` in the createuserwizard  and also   RequireEmail="false".

from default template following section need to remove

```
<p>
    <asp:Label ID="EmailLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Email">E-mail:</asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="EmailRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Email" 
            CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="E-mail is required." ToolTip="E-mail is required." 
            ValidationGroup="RegisterUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</p>
```

## EDIT

set `requiresUniqueEmail="false"` in your providers sections in web config as well.

Reference from [MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.createuserwizard.requireemail.aspx)

> If the membership provider specified in the MembershipProvider
>   property requires a unique e-mail address for new users, you must set
>   the RequireEmail property to true so that the UI for entering an
>   e-mail address is displayed. Otherwise, the user will see the
>   EmailRequiredErrorMessage but have no way to enter an e-mail address.

Comment: Actually username in my registration form is also email.So I dont need of email address.I removed it from form but when I try to create user then it gives me error 'Please enter valid email address'

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the createuserwizard into templates and throw out the email field. 
How to do this? See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178342(v=vs.80).aspx